# SharePoint sites from another tenant under my domain

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've a customer who is able to see sites from another tenant under their own sharepoint domain. They are using some cross tenancy setup.

When I try to get list of sites using Graph API, they can only see sites from their own tenant and not from cross tenant. To figure out the issue, I'm trying to create the same setup on my end, that is, to be able to see sharepoint sites from another tenant into mine.

I'm not able to figure out how to do that. If I simply share the sharepoint site with user in another tenant, it creates an external user in source tenant and site is only accessible to external user under source tenant's sharepoint domain.

Is it possible to build the same setup? How to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

It's sounds as though your client is using the Multi-Geo facilities of SharePoint Online. Customers can setup additional tenants in other geographical regions via the SharePoint admin center, this is mainly used for global businesses. You can find more information about this from the link below:

[Now available: Multi-Geo in SharePoint and Office 365 Groups](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/now-available-multi-geo-in-sharepoint-and-office-365-groups/ba-p/263302)